# Kommasetzung: »Sehe ich leckeres Essen – etwa eine Himbeertorte – so werde ich hungrig.«

Tags: comma

Der Satz

> Sehe ich leckeres Essen, so werde ich hungrig.

braucht ein Komma, um den Hauptsatz vom Nebensatz zu trennen. Wenn ich nun in Gedankenstrichen eine Ergänzung zum »Essen« einfüge, verschwindet das Komma oder bleibt es? Und an welcher Stelle? Welche der folgenden Varianten ist also richtig?

> Sehe ich leckeres Essen – etwa eine Himbeertorte – so werde ich hungrig.
>
> Sehe ich leckeres Essen – etwa eine Himbeertorte –, so werde ich hungrig.
>
> Sehe ich leckeres Essen – etwa eine Himbeertorte, – so werde ich hungrig.

Comment: Das _»so«_ nach dem Einschub ist übrigens verzichtbar, würde ich streichen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unter der Rubrik 'Sprachwissen' meint [der Online-Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/gedankenstrich) dazu:

> D 46:
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Zum umschließenden Text gehörende Satzzeichen dürfen nicht weggelassen werden <§ 85>.
>
>    - Er sagte – wie immer –, dass er nichts wisse.
>    - Verächtlich sagte er – er wandte kaum den Kopf dabei –: »Das ist eine Fälschung.«
>    - Sie verschweigt – leider! –, wen sie mit ihrem Vorwurf gemeint hat."

Die mittlere Version wäre demnach korrekt. Sie wirkt allerdings gegenüber einem lediglich durch Kommas abgetrennten Einschub umständlich und für mich bei näherem Hinsehen etwas aufgebläht. Ich würde bevorzugen:

> Sehe ich leckeres Essen, etwa eine Himbeertorte, so werde ich hungrig.

Beim Lesen würde mir die Gedankenstrich-Version aber wohl nicht weiter auffallen.

Comment: Danke, auch für die Quelle.